# How to auto-receive all Gmail messages in a Google Group

Tags: gmail, google-groups, email-forwarding

I am using a Google Workspace account and wanted to create a backup of all the emails received in my Gmail Inbox so that even after cleaning the inbox (deleting the emails from Gmail), the backup of emails would be there in Google Groups.

To do this, I am thinking of creating a google group with only one member (me).
After deleting the emails from my Email ID, the emails will still be present in the Google group.

But to achieve this, if I add a Gmail forwarding rule, then I might receive all the messages from my name instead of the original sender's name.
Is there a way through which I can auto-receive the original messages on Google Group which I received on my Email ID?

Comment: Hello @AnchitPhoenix, I have posted an answer! Would you mind checking if it solves your question?

Answer (score 0):

**You won't be receiving the email from your email address when adding a forwarding rule.**

Therefore, if you plan on forwarding all the incoming mail to your group, you should proceed by adding a forwarding rule and adding the email address of the group.

Afterwards, you will end up receiving the email in the group looking something similar to this:

[image: group convo]

#### Reference

- [Automatically forward Gmail messages to another account](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957).

Comment: Thanks @ale13. I'll check the suggestion and get back if this solves the question.